# Magento CMS Variables not rendering

Tags: magento, variables, rendering, magento-1.7

I have been searching and experimenting for days now on a solution for getting custom product attribute data into a static block. I decided to go ahead and use a call to a template file that defines the call to the products attribute.

The problem however, is that my Magento Community 1.7 installation doesnt render any variables, either within CMS pages, product attributes, or static blocks. I have seen everwhere that this is the way to do it. I put in something such as the following:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="/catalog/product/compatibility.phtml"}}
```

After saving, and making sure that HTML on the frontend is set to yes, I check to see if it worked. What I see is the exact code of the variable and not that it even tried to access the template file. I have even tried inserting stock variables (such as a widget or even just the store name) into a page/static block to see if they render but they dont NONE do.

Am I missing something? Is there something that needs to be enabled for variables to work at all on my site? Spent 4 solid days ripping my hair out already

Answer (score 1):

Please forgive me if this is too simple, but are you making sure you click to hide/disable the WYSIWYG editor before pasting the code into the blocks?

If you paste the code directly into the WYSIWYG editpr it will encode the tag and stop it being parsed properly.

also, you don't need to leading slash in the template path:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/compatibility.phtml"}}
```